# MYSQL Query not showing data properly

Tags: php, mysql

I am performing a filter by selected value this how my database looks like:

```
contactgroup  media  gender  age  isdelete  married  children driverslicens restatus retype
        -----------------------------------------------------------
        contactgroup1     SMS        Male     28     0   yes   yes     yes   owner    apart           
        contactgroup1     SMS        Female   26     0   no    null    no     rent  house
        contactgroup2     SMS        Male     32     0   null   no      null    owner  null
        contactgroup2     SMS        Male     38     0   yes    yes     no      null   null
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM contact
  where isdeleted = 0
    AND contactgroup in ('Contactgroup1', '')
    and media = 'sms'
    AND (`gender` = 'female' OR `gender` = 'male' OR `gender` is null)
    AND (`married` = 'yes' OR `married` = 'no' OR `married` is null)
    AND (`children` = 'yes' OR `children` = 'no' OR `children` is null)
    AND (`driverslicense` = 'yes' OR `driverslicense` = 'no' OR `driverslicense` is null)
    AND (`retype` = 'owner' OR `retype` = 'renting' OR `retype` is null)
    AND (`restatus` = 'apart' OR `restatus` = 'house' OR `restatus` is null)
    and age BETWEEN 18 AND 60
```

This query should show the data regarding the `contactgroup1`, but its showing all the four data can anyone tell me why it’s showing all the data where I went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to organize your query and group OR conditions

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  contact 
WHERE isdeleted = 0 
  AND contactgroup IN ('Contactgroup1', '') 
  AND media = 'sms' 
  AND (
    `gender` = 'female' 
    OR `gender` = 'male' 
    OR `gender` = 'null'
  ) 
  AND age BETWEEN 18 
  AND 60
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b7112/2)

**Edit as question is updated with new column**

You need to identify null by using `IS NULL`

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  contact 
WHERE isdelete = 0 
  AND contactgroup IN ('Contactgroup1', '') 
  AND media = 'sms' 
  AND (
    `gender` = 'female' 
    OR `gender` = 'male' 
    OR `gender` = 'null'
  ) 
  AND (
    `married` = 'yes' 
    OR `married` = 'no' 
    OR `married` IS NULL
  ) 
  AND age BETWEEN 18 
  AND 60
```

### [Demo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae7a7/2)

Comment: thanks for reply it works,but i added new coloumn please check my edieted code,this time this query not showing any data

Comment: hi @M M Khalid Junaid,there is another issue i found i added more coloumns this is my new query  
SELECT * FROM contact where isdeleted = 0 AND contactgroup in ('Contactgroup1', '') and media = 'sms' AND (`gender` = 'female' OR `gender` = 'male' OR `gender` is null) AND (`married` = 'yes' OR `married` = 'no' OR `married` is null) AND (`children` = 'yes' OR `children` = 'no' OR `children` is null) AND (`driverslicense` = 'yes' OR `driverslicense` = 'no' OR `driverslicense` is null) AND (`restatus` = 'apart' OR `restatus` = 'house' OR `restatus` is null) and age BETWEEN 18 AND 60

Comment: @Xavi see my comment in fiddle you have used wrong column name against values [**fiddle here columns name issue**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5b1/6) and also see [**correct fiddle here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5b1/8) hope you got my point

Answer (score 1):

Conditions in queries need to be popped in backets where you want some more than rudimentary logic applied to the search:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    contact 
where 
    isdeleted = 0 
    AND contactgroup in ('Contactgroup1', '') 
    and media = 'sms' 
    AND
    ( 
        `gender` = 'female' 
        OR `gender` = 'male' 
        OR `gender` = 'null' 
    )
    and age BETWEEN 18 AND 60
```

Any where clauses that introduce an `OR` statement will basically cause the database to ignore any of the other AND statements and return any matching data.

In your query, you had

```
OR `gender` = 'male' 
OR `gender` = 'null'
```

Which basically meant bring back any rows that matched this data. The change in the query now makes it that all the other `AND` statements have to be met - as long as at least ONE of the `OR` statements is met inside the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

use brackets around your `OR`-conditions like this:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  contact 
WHERE isdeleted = 0
AND contactgroup in ('Contactgroup1', '')
AND media = 'sms' 
AND (gender = 'female' OR gender = 'male' OR gender = 'null')
AND age BETWEEN 18 AND 60
```

this is called **[Operator Precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html)** - `AND` is more important than `OR`, so if you don't use brackets, it's like you're doing this:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  contact
WHERE (isdeleted = 0 AND contactgroup in ('Contactgroup1', '') and media = 'sms' AND gender = 'female')
OR (gender = 'male')
OR (gender = 'null' AND age BETWEEN 18 AND 60)
```